# Binding label to bottom-center of scene - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, position

I am trying to figure out how to center and bind a label perfectly at the bottom of a scene. I have a simple test application here to show what I am working with and what my issue is.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LabelTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

        Label label = new Label("Testing testing 1 2 3");

        label.layoutXProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().divide(2).subtract(label.getWidth() / 2));   //Should align label to horizontal center, but it is off  
        label.layoutYProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().subtract(label.getHeight() + 35));          //Aligns the label to bottom of scene

        root.getChildren().add(label);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

The logic behind my positioning makes sense to me, so I am not sure why it is not horizontally centered. I have included a screenshot below to show what the output looks like:

[image]

And below is more of what I am wanting it to look like (still off by a bit, but you get the point)

[image]

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let layout managers do the layout for you:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LabelTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Label label = new Label("Testing testing 1 2 3");
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        //center label by
        //BorderPane.setAlignment(label, Pos.CENTER);
        //root.setBottom(label);
        //OR
        root.setBottom(new StackPane(label));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This avoids using bindings and trying to offset the center of the label. Thank you!

Comment: @Brent Note the `StackPane` is not strictly necessary. You could also set the bottom to the `Label` directly and then call `BorderPane.setAlignment(theLabel, Pos.CENTER)`. That's not to say either approach is better than the other.

Comment: @Slaw thanks for the comment. I added this option to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are taking the values of width/height at the time of binding. And at this instance it will be 0 as they are not yet rendered. You need bind those properties as well for computing.

```
label.layoutXProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().divide(2).subtract(label.widthProperty().divide(2)));
label.layoutYProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().subtract(label.heightProperty().add(35)));
```